# sending mail using php mail function XAMPP 5.5-19

Tags: php, html, forms, email, sendmail

I new to `php` and wanted to write a program that receives information from a form and sends that information using `php` mail function. I am using `XAMPP 5.5-19` for my set-up. I researched a few topics on how to get this program working but have had no success. When I look at my `phpinfo();` it reads the following:

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F
sendmail_from = no value

my code

```
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Need More Information Contact Us!</h3>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </div>
            <label for="tele">Number</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="tele" />
            </div>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <div>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="subject"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" />
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sub']))
            {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $number = $_POST['tele'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $to = 'example@gmail.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $name,$number);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

I know this is a recurring topic but I had no luck on the articles I've researched. Thank you everyone who provides input and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working on localhost?

If yes, then SMTP is not working on localhost, otherwise your code is perfect.

Comment: Yes I am working on localhost I have tried to reconfiguring my php.ini following the link suggested from Antony Gibbs.

Comment: Is there anything that can do to fix the SMTP issue??

Comment: no..SMTP is only working on live hosting server..according to me SMTP can't find port on localhost so it's not working..

Answer (score 1):

Put your php part before any html. That way if your user submit is valid you can redirect the page.

See php header. ALso look at user data validations methods on the web. Basic rule, never trust user submit data.

Having said that, in your form add a hidden field for seeing when a form is used.

```
`<input type='hidden' name='sub' value='1'>`
```

Your mail function basically had three parts, 4th is optional. And you can use that to get real fancy.

mail(to, subject, message);

so in your code;

```
$msg = $name."\r\n";
$msg .= $number."\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg);
```

you can validate;
    $mail_status = mail($to, $subject, $msg);
    if($mail_status) 
    {do something}`
    else {do this when error}

on xampp, if there is no error it will be blank or it will do the {do something}, depnding how you wrote the code

Answer (score 1):

Open your sendmail folder (/usr/sbin/sendmail according to your phpinfo).
Turn on the debugger in the sendmail.ini file

```
; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging
debug_logfile=debug.log
```

Do a new request and see what the debug.log file says. For example missing authentication for smtp.google.com.

I'd also like to point out that on fresh installs you have to update php.ini to use the sendmail.exe, but I guess that's already taken care of judging by your phpinfo.

**Edit:**

To be sure, please check your php.ini file and find the following line:

```
sendmail_path =
```

If it's commented out with a `;` in front of it, remove the `;`.
According to an article I just read about sendmail with MAMP, you could also try to type your email address after the path.

For example: `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  yourname@example.com`

**Another thing, since you couldn't find sendmail.ini**

What files are inside your sendmail folder? I believe the sendmail script don't have a file extension on MAMP. In WAMP its an executable program (`.exe`)

Comment: My XAMPP file contain a sendmail.php file but nat a sendmail.ini file what should I do?

Comment: I updated my post, please read and try the new suggestions :)